# How to fetch SQL Server procedure returned value?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I'm trying to execute the procedure down below using Laravel query builder and the result always empty array,

SQL Procedure

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FConvTxtUnt] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @itmid int ,
    @number numeric(12,2) 
)
RETURNS nvarchar(150)
AS
BEGIN
--     
    declare @txtunitqty as nvarchar(150)
    set  @txtunitqty=''

    declare @factors as numeric(12,2)
    declare @result as int
    declare @result2 as numeric(12,2)

    set @result=1
    declare tcur  cursor for 
    select itemunitid,unitname 
    from stock_ItemsUnits
    inner join  stock_Units on stock_Units.unitid=stock_ItemsUnits.unitid 
    where itmid = @itmid 
    order by itemunitid
                
   open tcur ;

   declare @Itemunitid int; 
   declare @unitname nvarchar(50);
   fetch next from tcur into @Itemunitid,@unitname
   while (@@fetch_status = 0)
   BEGIN
      set @factors = (
          select EXP(SUM(LOG(factor)))  
          from  stock_ItemsUnits
          where itmid = @itmid and Itemunitid>=@Itemunitid 
      )
  
      if ( @factors=1)
      begin
         set   @txtunitqty=@txtunitqty +'/'+cast (@number as nvarchar(50))+@unitname
      end
      else
      begin
         set @result= @number/@factors
         set @result2= @number%@factors  
         set   @txtunitqty=@txtunitqty +'/'+cast (@result as nvarchar(50))+@unitname
      end
      set @number=@result2

      fetch next from tcur into @Itemunitid,@unitname;
   end

   close tcur;
   deallocate tcur;

   RETURN @txtunitqty

END
```

Implementation code,

```
return DB::select("EXEC FConvTxtUnt ?,?", [$itemId ,$quantity] );
```

The result always seems like,

```
[]
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong, considering that I don't have permission to modify the procedure itself, which I can't change the return to output.

Comment: Honestly, i would recommend rewriting that function though. Multi-line scalar functions can run slowly, and a `WHILE` in SQL runs *very** slowly. I would strongly recommend rewriting your function to be an inline table value function, which uses a set based solution.

Comment: That cursor is a horror show, it's going to be really slow. Looks like you can do this with a window function `EXP(SUM(LOG(factor)) OVER (PARTITION BY itmid ORDER BY Itemunitid DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will focus on the PHP part of the problem. You are trying to execute a function, not a procedure, so you simply need to change the statement:

```
DB::select("SELECT dbo.FConvTxtUnt(?, ?)", [$itemId, $quantity]);
```

I understand that you can't change the function, because you *... don't have permission to modify the procedure ...*, but you need to consider very carefully the comments about using loops and cursors.